# Best Work around to Sync .txt file with iCloud in ios6 ios7 and ios8 compatibility

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, synchronization, icloud

In my application i used to synced text file with iCloud server. But now with ios 8 file name it is not working. file name have .icloud suffix. so my functionality is broken.

i have used https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync Api to sync with iCloud.

if anyone know any better solution than can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: me also have the same problem..
Did u get any solution.?

Comment: @Sabareesh no still not found any perfect and working solution for that.